# how to automatically remove the redundant .coe file in vivado by automating tcl script?

Tags: console, tcl, fpga, vivado

i have been assigned a project where there is a redundant /missing .coe file under coefficients file directory which no longer required in the given project of vivado. project will open in vivado through .tcl script file by running it in tcl console. i have been instructed to do some modification in the tcl script file to resolve this redundant .coe file in coefficient files directory. i am complete novice person in tcl programming language although i am learning basics of tcl form xilinx user guide (ug-894).

what I need to modify in tcl script. which command is used to resolve this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about Vivado, but the usual way to delete a file in a Tcl script is

```
file delete $filename
```

See documentation at https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/file.htm#M12